# how to fix 'The type or namespace name 'PlayerManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

í am trying to access the playermanager from ThirdPersonUserControl but it is not working and giving ther error

I have tried referencing but still no good

class 1

public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour{}

class 2

public PlayerManager manager;

```
    private void Start()
    {

        manager = gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerManager>();
    }
```

Comment: Sometimes for me VisualStudio as well doesn't recognize newly added classes while Unity just compiles fine. When it occurs in 80% of the cases it is solved by closing and reopening VS. In the rest of cases you can try to close Unity and VS, delete everything except the `Assets`, `ProjectSettings` and `Packages` folders and let Unity recompile the whole project (might have to switch again to the correct build target)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell with so little information. Ideally a *compilable* piece of code that people can drop into a blank project.

Do both classes/files use the same namespace? To use classes in another namespace, the file must contain a "using directive", e.g. `using System;` or you must use the complete name, e.g. `System.Console.Write("Test");` for the `Console` class in the `System` namespace.

Are they both in the same project? Classes in different projects, or external DLLs will also need an assembly reference, in Visual Studio you can see these in the "Solution Explorer", if you expand your project and then "References", which will be at the top of the project.

Usually with Visual Studio (or other IDEs) for things like this it will underline the error in red, and can provide some hints on how to also fix it. In the case of Visual Studio, right click "Quick Actions and Refactorings..." or with the default shortcut `Ctrl + .` it may offer to add an using directive or an assembly reference for you automatically.

Comment: the second script has namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson but the first one don't have any namespace and sorry for not providing full information